# Skeletal_tracker crashes

Tags: ros, openni-kinect, hand-interaction, mit-ros-pkg, skeletal-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to make the hand_interaction demos working but it still doesn't even if I follow exactly  the instruction of http://www.ros.org/wiki/mit-ros-pkg/KinectDemos/dback.

I installed DiamondBack on Ubuntu 10.10. I can't use 10.04 because I need the multitouch support for my project.

The openni_kinect stacks of the ros installation works perfectly fine. But the demos doesn't. I want to use the hand_detection tracking because it seems more performant that the openni_tracker alone.

When launching hand_detector, I noticed that the process skeletal_tracker was always relaunching:

```
quentin@desktop-quentin:~/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg-experimental/nifun$ roslaunch hand_interaction hand_detector.launch
... logging to /home/quentin/.ros/log/945ec950-65c4-11e0-ad85-643150236fec/roslaunch-desktop-quentin-3919.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://desktop-quentin:52801/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /openni_node1/use_indices
 * /openni_node1/depth_registration
 * /openni_node1/image_time_offset
 * /openni_node1/depth_frame_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_mode
 * /openni_node1/debayering
 * /rosversion
 * /openni_node1/projector_depth_baseline
 * /openni_node1/rgb_frame_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_rgb_translation
 * /openni_node1/depth_time_offset
 * /openni_node1/image_mode
 * /openni_node1/shift_offset
 * /openni_node1/device_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_rgb_rotation

NODES
  /
    openni_node1 (openni_camera/openni_node)
    kinect_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    handdetector (hand_interaction/detectskelhands)
    ressetter (dynamic_reconfigure/dynparam)
    skel_tracker (skeletal_tracker/tracker)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [3933]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 945ec950-65c4-11e0-ad85-643150236fec
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3946]
started core service [/rosout]
process[openni_node1-2]: started with pid [3953]
process[kinect_base_link-3]: started with pid [3955]
process[kinect_base_link1-4]: started with pid [3959]
process[kinect_base_link2-5]: started with pid [3960]
process[kinect_base_link3-6]: started with pid [3962]
process[handdetector-7]: started with pid [3972]
process[ressetter-8]: started with pid [3974]
process[skel_tracker-9]: started with pid [3975]
[/openni_node1] Number devices connected: 1
Warning: recursive print statement has occurred.  Throwing out recursive print.
Warning: recursive print statement has occurred.  Throwing out recursive print.
Waiting for service /openni_camera/set_parameters...
Warning: recursive print statement has occurred.  Throwing out recursive print.
Warning: recursive print statement has occurred.  Throwing out recursive print.
Warning: recursive print statement has occurred.  Throwing out recursive print.
InitFromXml failed: File not found!
[skel_tracker-9] process has died [pid 3975, exit code 4].
log files: /home/quentin/.ros/log/945ec950-65c4-11e0-ad85-643150236fec/skel_tracker-9*.log
respawning...
[skel_tracker-9] restarting process
process[skel_tracker-9]: started with pid [4299]

etc...
```

I tried to launch this node alone and got this:

```
quentin@desktop-quentin:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_tracker$ roslaunch skeletal_tracker follower.launch 
... logging to /home/quentin/.ros/log/c051c732-65c5-11e0-826c-643150236fec/roslaunch-desktop-quentin-4554.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://desktop-quentin:33809/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosversion
 * /rosdistro

NODES
  /
    skel_tracker (nifun/tracker)
    follower (nifun/faceme.py)
    create_driver (irobot_create_2_1/driver.py)
    kinect_to_create_tf (tf/static_transform_publisher)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [4568]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to c051c732-65c5-11e0-826c-643150236fec
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [4581]
started core service [/rosout]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [nifun/tracker]: Cannot locate node of type [tracker] in package [nifun]
process[follower-3]: started with pid [4584]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [irobot_create_2_1/driver.py]: Cannot locate installation of package irobot_create_2_1: [rospack] couldn't find package [irobot_create_2_1]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/diamondback/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/quentin/kinect_demos/motion_planning_common:/home/quentin/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg-experimental:/home/quentin/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg:/home/quentin/kinect_demos/perception_pcl_addons:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks]
process[kinect_to_create_tf-5]: started with pid [4595]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/quentin/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg-experimental/nifun/src/faceme.py", line 3, in <module>
    roslib.load_manifest('nifun')
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/launcher.py", line 69, in load_manifest
    sys.path = _generate_python_path(package_name, [], os.environ) + sys.path
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/launcher.py", line 125, in _generate_python_path
    raise roslib.packages.InvalidROSPkgException("While loading package '%s': %s"%(d.package, str(e)))
roslib.packages.InvalidROSPkgException: While loading package 'kinect_tools': While loading package 'eigen3': Cannot locate installation of package eigen3: [rospack] couldn't find package [eigen3]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/diamondback/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/quentin/kinect_demos/motion_planning_common:/home/quentin/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg-experimental:/home/quentin/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg:/home/quentin/kinect_demos/perception_pcl_addons:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks]
[follower-3] process has died [pid 4584, exit code 1].
log files: /home/quentin/.ros/log/c051c732-65c5-11e0-826c-643150236fec/follower-3*.log
respawning...
[follower-3] restarting process
process[follower-3]: started with pid [4610]

etc...
```

Thank you very much for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9721/skeletal_tracker-crashes/) by [Quentin](https://answers.ros.org/users/420/quentin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2011-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After 1 week and half on this problem, I found the answer 20 minutes after having finally asked the question here (http://kinect-with-ros.976505.n3.nabble.com/Ros-kinect-skel-tracker-issue-td2790186.html).

The real error is this one: `InitFromXml failed: File not found!`.
It comes from the line

```
std::string configFilename = ros::package::getPath("openni") + "/lib/SamplesConfig.xml";
```

of `main.cpp`.

While with the cturtle distribution, the file exists,with diamondback it doesn't. We can find this file on the official OpenNi git repository. The solution is to download it in the lib directory of the openni package:

```
sudo wget -P `rospack find openni`/lib https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI/raw/43c256b554dcbe478644be73e29af16b3470f1c1/Data/SamplesConfig.xml --no-check-certificate
```

It does the trick for me.

I also found it at the root of the openni_tracker package under the name `openni_tracker.xml`.

I hope the MIT team will fix it.

---

Originally posted by [Quentin](https://answers.ros.org/users/420/quentin/) with karma: 36 on 2011-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2